# Custom adapter for ListView repeating objects

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, repeat

i've a custom adapter to populate an ListView, i have an ArrayList, when i execute the program the ListView is entire populated with the first object from arraylist.

I searched for an similar question here on stackoverflow and i didnt find a solution, plase, someone help me

Heres playerAdapter.java

```
public class playerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player>{
private ArrayList<Player> entries;
private Activity activity;

public playerAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Player> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView item1;
    public TextView item2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemplayer, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nomecharlist);
        //holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.small);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final Player custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.item1.setText(custom.getNomePlayer());
        //holder.item2.setText(custom.getSecond());
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is with your code, but I do know that's it's much too complicated. Try something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemplayer, null);
    }
    final Player custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null)
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomecharlist)).setText(custom.getNomePlayer());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You're right, theres no problemn with the getView, its with my objects, sorry!!!!!